# How to pass custom marker to polyline decorator

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I am working with leaflet appliction, where user draw some shape.
A polyline added to that shape using leaflet.polyline.decorators.
I just want to know how to pass custom marker to L.Symbol.marker().

For example i am passing the custom marker but its not working.

**Script**

```
var myCustomMarker= L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'assets/img/wallE.png',
                    iconSize: [30, 30], // size of the icon
                    iconAnchor: [5, 18], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                });
    new L.Marker(e.latlng, { icon: wallIcon, draggable: false }).addTo(curr);
        polylineWall.addLatLng([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]).addTo(curr);
        // Add coordinate to the polyline
        var decorator = L.polylineDecorator(polylineWall, {
        patterns: [
                { offset: 0, endOffset: 0, repeat: '10px', symbol: new L.Symbol.marker(myCustomMarker)}
                   ]
                   }).addTo(curr);
```

**Console Error**

> Uncaught Error: iconUrl not set in Icon options (see the docs).

If someone have knowledge about this problem please help.Thanks for your time.